# Validate two or more values on the same table row

Tags: jquery, html-table

How can one apply validation to two or more values on the same row?

I need to make sure that the user does not fill out the PUID input without selecting the corresponding checkbox, and vice versa.

In that case, I want to show an error if he clicks on the 'Click ME' button.

[image]

**EDIT:** Using the disabled attribute is not helpful because a user can still mark the checkbox and leave the input empty
**JSFIDDLE:**

https://jsfiddle.net/gczr3yxd/5/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped mytable" id="table">
    <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>

        <th>#</th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>App</th>
        <th>PUID</th>
        <th>ID</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr class="row">
        <td><input class="case" name="case[]" type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>Prod1</td>
        <td>AppName1</td>
        <td>
          <input class="form-control" id="usr" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td class="prAppId">a0L2000000Rpc1UEAR</td>

      </tr>

      <tr class="row">
        <td><input class="case" name="case[]" type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>Prod2</td>
        <td>AppName2</td>
        <td>
          <input class="form-control" id="usr" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td class="prAppId">a0L2000000Rpc1bEAB</td>

      </tr>

      <tr class="row">
        <td><input class="case" name="case[]" type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>Prod3</td>
        <td>AppName3</td>
        <td>
          <input class="form-control" id="usr" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td class="prAppId">a0L250000040FhzEAE</td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button onclick="getTableRowData()">Click ME</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you disable text boxes, and enable them only if the corresponding checkbox gets checked?

Comment: but that still won't make sure the input will be filled out. user can mark the checkbox and leave the input empty

When the button is clicked, I want to know if the checkbox was marked and the input was not empty

I will update the question

Comment: You can add/remove `required` property of input on checkbox check and uncheck.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("change",".case",function(){
    var td = $(this)
    if($(td). prop("checked") == true){
        $(this).parent().nextAll().eq(2).find("input").prop( "disabled",false )
    }else{
        $(this).parent().nextAll().eq(2).find("input").prop( "disabled" , true)
    }

});
```

and for the html add disable for the input field like

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
     <table class="table table-hover table-striped mytable" id="table">
    <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>

        <th>#</th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>App</th>
        <th>PUID</th>
        <th>ID</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr class="row">
        <td><input class="case" name="case[]" type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>Prod1</td>
        <td>AppName1</td>
        <td>
          <input class="form-control" disabled id="usr" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td class="prAppId">a0L2000000Rpc1UEAR</td>

      </tr>

      <tr class="row">
        <td><input class="case" name="case[]" type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>Prod2</td>
        <td>AppName2</td>
        <td>
          <input class="form-control" disabled id="usr" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td class="prAppId">a0L2000000Rpc1bEAB</td>

      </tr>

      <tr class="row">
        <td><input class="case" name="case[]" type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>Prod3</td>
        <td>AppName3</td>
        <td>
          <input class="form-control" disabled id="usr" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td class="prAppId">a0L250000040FhzEAE</td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button onclick="getTableRowData()">Click ME</button>
</div>
```

---

[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gczr3yxd/24/)

Comment: Thanks @coolmonster, however this solution creates a new problem. now a user can check on the checkbox,click on the button and the input could remain empty...which is what I wanted to prevent in the first place.

Comment: OK you didn't mention that... So you want  if  value of any input is empty then button should not do anything